# How to arrange data zigzag way from one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to arrange data zigzag way from one column?

Is this possible?

Many Thanks
[image: example]

Comment: I think you might need to explain this a little better as the above appears the same before and after. Maybe use a table generator to include sample data, and images (though not everyone can work with these).

Comment: Do you mean transposed? Try paste special or depending on your Excel version there is a transposed function

Comment: They appear to not only want tranposed but to split that transpose across rows. How do you determine when to split across a new row? It is after every third entry in the 6 entry sample so insufficient grounds for an assumption.

Answer (score 2):

In **B1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROW()-1)*3,0)
```

and copy both across and downward:

[image]

a **better** alternative formula *(non-volatile)*:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,COLUMNS($A:A)+3*(ROWS($1:1)-1),0)
```

**Note:**

Using relatively simple formulas it is always possible to map a single column or a single row into a 2-D table.  It is also easy to map a table into a single column or row.

Comment: Nice. Though this assumes a split every 3 which the OP still hasn't confirmed. I am also not sure why they say "zig-zag" but maybe that's my understanding of zig-zag. In your solution would they just amend the +3 if they actually split on 4 instead?

Comment: @QHarr Yes...........the ***3*** in the formula corresponds to the desired width of the *2-D* table.

Comment: I think you should stress that `INDEX` is preferred over `OFFSET` because `INDEX` is non-volatile. Otherwise I agree with your answer. +1